# redirecting example.com/wp-login.php and example.com/wp-admin to a subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We just moved WordPress to its own directory but alot of people at this org have example.com/wp-login.php and example.com/wp-admin/whatever bookmarked.

I have the following redirects in my htaccess file, which work locally but do not work on my staging (AWS) environment.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^/wp-login.php?$ /wordpress/wp-login.php [R,L]
  RewriteRule ^/wp-admin/(.*)$ /wordpress/wp-admin/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

if I goto my staging site staging.example.com/wp-login.php I get a 404 page.

Maybe I just dont understand rewrite roles, but that first block should match the example.com/wp-login.php and redirect it to the new subdirectory but not, it just 404s at the wp-login.php

We have varnish running, could varnish be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relative path (starting without a leading slash) in `RewriteRule` directive if your rules are in an htaccess files .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php?$ /wordpress/wp-login.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ /wordpress/wp-admin/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: seems to work for the admin pages, but if I attempt example.com/wp-login.php i still get the 404